# Arranging models and controllers in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have an application pretty much nearing completion in Laravel which I just lately began using and I have to say, I am loving it.

My application works fine, my question relates to best practice and opinion really.

Say I have the following hypothetical simple set-up.

Route: Brand -> This page loads an index of shoes for this brand.

Controllers: BrandController, ShoeController

Models: Brand, Shoe

At present when someone goes to the brand route with an id, I am calling the ShoeController to load a view with a list of shoes for that brand.

Is this the correct way to organise things or should all code for the Brand route be encapsulated in the BrandController and just call the Shoe Model to return the results within the BrandController?

I hope this is clear enough as an example.

Comment: Think of it like this way, Shoe is just one more category/article, what if u have jacket, you will go with JacketController? nah.  Shoe as article/category can have common some things with other articles, price, description, name, etc. Maybe you can make use of Abstract Factory design pattern or Factory Method. Just opinion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're totally free to organize. But itsn't very nice to combine different subjects.

Let me give an example:

If you've a route, for example: /brand/overview/1, so you can call the shoe model from your brand controller for getting the shoes with brand_id 1.

On the view, you can link directly to a shoe route (shoe controller), for example: /shoe/details/5.

Generally, controllers are thin controllers. Their jobs are:

- delegating tasks
- consolidating data

So don't commingle CRUD (create / read / update / delete) methods for different entities.

Comment: Perfect, thanks very much. This is what I had wanted to hear, I was of the same mindset that its tidier to give the retrieval methods a home in their correct container but wanted to be sure in case I was mistaken. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

In general it's ok, but try thinking on the future.

Currently "brand" page display a list of shoes, from a specific brand.

Main shoes page, simply display all shoes list.

Both pages render in the

```
ShoeController
```

just with different parameter of brand.

Now lets say you got bigger and you have bags and other products from a brand, you would probably want to show them on your "brand" route...

So of course you could change it in the future, but those things should be taken in consideration

Comment: A very valid point which I will take into consideration for sure. Thanks for the help.